# Division of a line segment in the given ration internally

Tags: geometric-construction

Before  I  state my problem description, would like to describe problem which was  stated before  my problem. So it is like this

> Given a line segment $AB$. You are required to divide it internally in the ratio
>   $2 : 3$.
>   steps for this  problem is following
>
> 1. Draw a ray $AC$ making an acute angle with $AB$.
> 2. Starting with $A$, mark off 5 points $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5$ 
>      at equal distances from the point $A$.
> 3. Join $C_5$ and $B$
> 4. Through $C_2$ (i.e. the second point), draw $C_2D$ parallel to $C_5B$ meeting $AB$ in $D$.
>
> Then $D$ is required point, which divides $AB$ segment into $2:3$ part.

Here is picture which demonstrate this procedure:
[image]

based on this information, I am trying to solve similar one

> Draw a line segment 7 cm long. Divide it internally in the ratio $3 : 4$. Measure each part. Also write the steps of construction.

So as I understood, because we had to divide into  ratio $2:3$ and we took $5$ points,in our case we have to take $7$ points right? Because of $3:4$ ration, with equal distance from starting $A$, of course first we should draw ray with acute angle,then took $7$ point,connect last point to one of the end of our segment (which equal to $7$cm) then choose $C_3$ and connect segment, intersection point would be desired point yes? Please tell me if I am wrong, also what should be length of each small segments, by which we divide large one?

Comment: yes it is  right

Comment: By small segments you mean those with the seven point (and A) as endpoints? It does not matter what their length is, anything constructable.   Just make them the same.

Comment: so my argument is correct?

Comment: @dato: Yes, your method is correct for the ratio $3:4$, and generalizes in a straightforward way to the ratio $m:n$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.  It all comes down to properties of parallel lines (you get equal angles, so similar triangles), or to put it another way, properties of scaling.

Comment: thanks very much @André Nicolas

Comment: @dato: I had forgotten to upvote!  You described your question very fully and clearly.

Comment: wish you everything best in your life,thanks

Comment: how we know that where is piont D ?
whether draw perpendicular to AB or perpendicular to AC at C2??